# PHP マニュアルへアクセスしたらセキュリティチェックが表示されるのですが、Please click hereを押しても大丈夫ですか？

Tags: php

[PHP マニュアル - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/index.php)

> Security Sicherheitsüberprüfung Unsere Systeme haben ungewöhnlichen
> Datenverkehr aus Ihrem Computernetzwerk festgestellt. Diese Seite
> überprüft, ob die Anfragen wirklich von Ihnen und nicht von einem
> Roboter gesendet werden.
>
> Bitte klicken Sie hier, wenn Sie kein Roboter sind.
>
> Security Check Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your
> computer network. This page checks to see if it is really you sending
> the requests and not a bot.
>
> Please click here to verify that you are not a bot.

Comment: プログラミングとは直接関係の無い質問のようにみえます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

プログラミングには無関係そうですが、何か重大な勘違いをしている様子なので

このメッセージは `www.php.net` 側が出力しているものです。あなたの PC にインストールされているセキュリティソフトがアクセス先を危険であると検出して出力しているものではありません。

> あなたのコンピュータから通常とは異なるトラフィックが来たことを(`www.php.net` 側の)セキュリティチェックシステムが検出しました。このページは、人間が要求したこと（ボットでないこと）をチェックするためのものです。
> あなたがボットでないのなら、それを検証するためここをクリックしてください。

ということなので、クリックしてかまいません（あなたがボットでないなら）
# ですがクリックする前にちょっと先を読むべし

現に今オイラが `www.php.net` をクリックしてみたところ普通にマニュアルが表示されましたので `www.php.net` 側がおかしくなっているとも思えないです。

会社や学校などでは社外ネットと社内ネットを分離するために社外へのアクセスには `http/https` プロキシを経由しなければならないところが多いのですが、そうなっていると社員何十人かが一斉にアクセスするとアクセス先 `www.php.net` から見て、１台の PC から異様に大量のアクセスがあったように見えてしまうことになります。メッセージ中「あなたのコンピュータ」はこの場合は社外アクセスを代行するプロキシサーバのことになります。

ここをクリックしてねをクリックすると、人間であることの証明として `recaptcha` などによるテストが行われることが多いのですがこれが極めてうざい上に、たいていの場合は単なる過剰検出（ false positive ）なだけなので、しばらく時間をおいてアクセスしてみるとか、プロキシサーバを通さない直接アクセスができる回線が別途あるならそちらでアクセスしてみるとか、そういう方向を試したほうがイラつきません。

Comment: 「 www.php.net をクリックしてみたところ普通にマニュアルが表示されました」。参考になりました。これまで一度もこのセキュリティチェック画面が表示されたことがなかったため、何かあったのではないかと思い質問しました……